# Number of points with integer co-ordinates inside $x^2+y^2=36$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, computational-geometry

**Question**:

> Find the number of points with integer co-ordinates that lie inside the circle: $$x^2+y^2=36$$

**My Approach**:

> I drew the figure and counted!
> I counted the number of points inside the $1^{st}$ quadrant and multiplied that by $4$.
> After that I moved on to count the points on the axes.
> Finally I was able to get the correct answer ($109$).

Is there a better way to solve these kind of questions?
Counting seems way too basic and time consuming.

Comment: This amounts the number of integers $(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2 \leq 36$

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I still see myself counting. Also, it's $<$ instead of $\leq$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of lattice points inside a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207950/number-of-lattice-points-inside-a-circle). The answer is $N(6)=113$ for $a^2=36$, so $a=6$.

Comment: There is also [Easy answer to Gauss's Circle Problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241165/easy-answer-to-gausss-circle-problem). Concerning $<$ or $\le$, it makes no difference for $36$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That doesn't answer the question. The accepted answer there just shows how to rule out options in an multiple choice question. And the other answer just counts from a figure.

Comment: @AnneBauval there is a difference. $<$ will have 109 solutions while $\leq$ would have 113 solutions including (6,0), (-6,0), (0,6), (0,-6).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well then the link should have been https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem instead, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but only a stackexchange site is a duplicate. There are a few ones available, and you are right, this one is one click further away.

Comment: Downvotes without comments aren't appreciated. (That too 3 at that!) May I know the reason kindly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a an slightly advanced way how to solve this problem. For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ one can consider $r(n):=|\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2: x^2+y^2=n\}|$. One can show that $r(n)=4\rho(n)$, where $\rho(n)=\sum \limits_{d\mid n}\chi_4(d)$, where $\chi_4$ is a non-principal character $\text{mod}\  4$, i.e. $\chi_4(d)=\sin \dfrac{\pi d}{2}$.

Easy to see that $$|\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2: x^2+y^2\leq 36\}|=1+4\sum \limits_{n=1}^{36}\sum \limits_{d\mid n}\sin \dfrac{\pi d}{2}=$$
$$=1+4\sum \limits_{d=1}^{36}\sin \frac{\pi d}{2}\sum\limits_{1\leq n\leq 36, d\mid n}1=$$ $$=1+4\sum \limits_{d=1}^{36}\sin \frac{\pi d}{2}\left\lfloor \frac{36}{d}\right\rfloor=$$ $$=1+4\sum \limits_{k=0}^{17}(-1)^{k}\left\lfloor \frac{36}{2k+1}\right\rfloor=$$ $$=1+4\left(\left\lfloor \frac{36}{1}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{36}{5}\right\rfloor+\dots+\left\lfloor \frac{36}{33}\right\rfloor\right)-$$ $$-4\left(\left\lfloor \frac{36}{3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{36}{7}\right\rfloor+\dots+\left\lfloor \frac{36}{35}\right\rfloor\right)=$$ $$=1+4(36+19)-4\cdot 27=113.$$

So the correct answer is actually $113$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1. Though I'll differ with you regarding: "Easy to see that".

Comment: @InanimateBeing, if it is unclear I can add more details. Just let me know.

Comment: In retrospect it seems unfair to accept my own answer. Thanks a lot for your answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:Well According to theorem of Pythagorean triplets, the only positive integer solution of the equation $$x^2+y^2=z^2$$ with $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$
is $$x=a^2-b^2, y=2ab$$ and $$z=a^2+b^2$$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$ with the fact that we can interchage the role of $(x,y)$.
So Positive integer and Negative integers will be found like this with some extension of $\gcd$. Others can be found trivillay by plugging $0$.

Remark:For Interior integer points you need to do find the solutions of $x^2+y^2=m^2$ for all integer $m<6$ to find it on circumference you nedd $m=6$ and all such solution can be found from above hint.

This is a Case Study Approach!!! Infact this tells you much more that is you can locate every coordinate inside the circle with integer coordinate value.

Comment: Downvotes without comments especially on answers aren't appreciated. If you don't like the answer, don't upvote it or perhaps still leave a comment. But this is an honest attempt at trying to tackle the problem and given that Gauss couldn't find a "perfect" way to do it (see link in the comments above) then expecting mere mortals isn't good.

Comment: I didn't downvote

Comment: I was standing for your own answer, someone downvoted it without any comments, I upvoted to negate it and also to recognize your attempt.

Comment: The main problem with this answer is that there's no reason $x^2 + y^2$ should be a square.  For example, with $x=1, y=1$ you get $1^2 + 1^2 = 2$.

Comment: I would say the main problem with this answer is it doesn't really help us in any way that I can see.  It doesn't matter what solutions to $x^2 + y^2 = m^2$ are possible as we need to count *all* the $x^2 + y^2 < m^2$ as well.

Comment: @fleablood and Robert thank you I got the point of both of you, I Guess Circle method works here.

Comment: In retrospect it seems unfair to accept my own answer. Thanks a lot for your answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Sure...

To be "inside" is to have $x^2 + y^2 \le 36$. if $x$ an integer $-6 \le x \le 6$ then we have $|y| \le \sqrt {36 - x^2}$ and the number of such natural (strictly positive) numbers for which $y$ can be is $\lfloor\sqrt{36 -x^2}\rfloor$.

Let's figure than for $x = 0,.... 6$.  then if $L_x = \lfloor\sqrt{36 -x^2}\rfloor =$  we have:

$L(0) = [\sqrt 36]=6; L(1) = [\sqrt 35] = 5; L(2) = [\sqrt 32]=5; L(3)= [\sqrt 27]=5; L(4)=[\sqrt{20}]=4; L(5)=\sqrt {11}=3; L(6)=\sqrt{0} = 0$.

If we allow that $y$ can be postive, or negative, or zero, then for $x$ the number of possible values we $|y| \le \sqrt{36 -x^2}$ would be $2L(x) + 1$.

So we have to do $\sum_{x=-6}^6 (2L(x) + 1)$.

And if $(x,y); x > 0$ is in the circle then $(-x,y)$ is in the circle as well so clearly $L(-x) = L(x)$.  So

$\sum_{x=-6}^6 (2L(x) + 1)=$

$\sum_{x=-6}^{-1}(2L(x) + 1) + (2L(0) + 1) + \sum_{x=1}^6 (2L(x) + 1)=$

$(2L(0) + 1) + 2\times (\sum_{x=1}^6(2L(x) +  1)=$

$(2L(0) + 1) + 2\times( 2\sum_{x=1}^6 L(x) + \sum_{x=1}^6 1) =$

$(2L(0) + 1) + 4\times \sum_{x=1}^6 L(x) + 2\times 6 =$

$(2\times 6 + 1) + 4(5+5+5+4+3+0) + 12=$

$13 + 4(22) + 12 =$

$13 + 88 + 12 = 113$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. +1. Your method, not involving graph, looks good, but it's simply what I also did while calculating the points in the circle - converted into all-mathematical equations which is great but it's not faster imho.

Comment: In retrospect it seems unfair to accept my own answer. Thanks a lot for your answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem 65, page 80, in Introduction to the Theory of Numbers  by Leonard Eugene Dickson:  the number of all representations of $2^k m$ (where $m$ is positive and odd)    by $x^2 + y^2 $   is $4E,$   where $E$ (for excess) is  the count of divisors of $m$  that are $1 \pmod 4$ minus the count of those $3 \pmod 4.$  Due to Jacobi...Evidently if $E$  comes out negative we just put zero.

I see, should add a column for cumulative sum..

Also, Jacobi's theorem does not say anything about $0$   which has just one representation, so we need to add $1$   to count all lattice points inside a circle.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
0&1&1 \\
1&4&5 \\
2&4&9\\
3& 0&9\\
4&4&13\\
5&8&21\\
6&0&21\\
7&0&21\\
8&4&25\\
9&4&29\\
10&8&37\\
11&0&37\\
12&0&37\\
13&8&45\\
14&0&45\\
15&0&45\\
16&4&49\\
17&8&57\\
18&4&61\\
19&0&61\\
20&8&69\\
21&0&69\\
22&0&69\\
23&0&69\\
24&0&69\\
25&12&81\\
26&8&89\\
27&0&89\\
28&0&89\\
29&8&97\\
30&0&97\\
31&0&97\\
32&4&101\\
33&0&101\\
34&8&109\\
35&0&109\\
36&4&113\\
\end{array}
$$

For strictly inside 36 we get 109, but if we are including 36 it becomes 113.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1. Though this method I think is even more tedious (unless someone is too good calculations but that I'm not).

Comment: @InanimateBeing  how many integer solutions to $x^2 + y^2 = 65 \; \; ? \; \; $

Comment: Pardon me, I take my words back. Yours is more efficient approach.

Comment: In retrospect it seems unfair to accept my own answer. Thanks a lot for your answer again.

Answer (score 0):

[Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem): This link was provided by DietrichBurde in the comments below the question. The OP found it to be really helpful (realizing it a bit late). 
Also note that the answer already provided by WillJagy and ZFR (kindly upvote their answer posts if you find this helpful) essentially employ the same ease of computation (and even the same expression is in play but in a different disguise) as one would do while solving the below expression but the below expression itself is more easier to understand/employ as it is a bit more "straight-forward". Citing the relevant parts from that link:

---

Consider a circle in $\Bbb R^2$ with center at the origin and radius $r\geq0$. Gauss's circle problem asks how many points there are inside this circle of the form $(m,n)$ where $m$  and $n$  are both integers. Since the equation of this circle is given in Cartesian coordinates by $x^2+y^2=r^2$ , the question is equivalently asking how many pairs of integers $m$ and $n$ there are such that
$$m^2+n^2\leq r^2$$
If the answer for a given $r$  is denoted by $N(r)$ then
the value of $N(r)$  can be given by several series. In terms of a sum involving the floor function it can be expressed as:
$$N(r)=1+4\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{r^2}{4i+1}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{r^2}{4i+3}\right\rfloor\right)$$

This is a consequence of Jacobi's two-square theorem, which follows almost immediately from the [Jacobi triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product).

Comment: Anyone who reads the post, know that how to increase the length of `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` which are $\lfloor$ and $\rfloor$ respectively? They did not automatically stretch themselves as I hoped they'd do.

Comment: \left \lfloor \right \rfloor

Comment: @ZFR thanks a lot!